# How to collect errors / warnings from redux selectors?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react and redux in my frontend app. I have a plenty of data that I'm loading from backend server that is stored in a redux store and this data is later transformed and combined with state generated by user actions.
Those transformations/combinations are done in selectors and so far I was able to develop the application without problems, however, those selectors grew bigger and now they contain a significant amount of logic, they combine and transform data from several places of the store and basically only those selectors know when something in the data is wrong. Now I want to notify the user when something in the data is not correct by showing a box with error/warning messages and I'm not sure how to do this properly. I can't dispatch an action from a selector (this would be stupid to have a side effect in selector), I don't want to duplicate those calculations in another selector only to find errors, having a global object to register those errors seems even worse.

Is there any pattern I could use here? Maybe instead of transformations in selectors I should calculate this "transformed" state and store it in redux store (so moving the calculations from the selector to thunk action)?

Comment: Why can't your selectors check to ensure they have everything they need and if not return the error(s) as props? Then your components can then respond to (e.g. by just rendering an appropriate message if there's an error instead of the normal view),

Comment: I want to collect the warnings that can happen in several selectors and present them in single error box component. So even if I return from selector a tuple like [expectedResults, warnings] then I will have to call N selectors again (duplicate calculations) and collect those warnings to present them in another component. I'm wondering if there is any pattern that will not require recalculation of everything.